# bash script: echo >> returns error "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, append, echo

Why isn't working this code?

```
#!/bin/bash

test="~/.test"

function fn_append () {

    echo "check vars: $1  ···  ${1} ··· $2"
    echo "check comm: echo \"$2\" >> $1"
        #this returns "No such file or directory"
    echo $2 >> $1
    echo $2 >> ${1}
    echo $2 >> "$1"
        #this creates file named $1
    echo $2 >> '$1'
        #this works (but it isn't enough)
    echo $2 >> ~/.test
        #this is the command Im trying to create.
    #echo "alias ll='ls -lstra'" >> ~/.test
}

fn_append ${test} "alias ll='ls -lstra'"
```

Executing outputs this:

```
check vars: ~/.test  ···  ~/.test ··· alias ll='ls -lstra'
check comm: echo "alias ll='ls -lstra'" >> ~/.test
./test.sh: line 9: ~/.test: No such file or directory
./test.sh: line 10: ~/.test: No such file or directory
./test.sh: line 11: ~/.test: No such file or directory
```

The file does exist (though even if it doesn't the script should work anyway) and I have permissions. The command works on terminal and hardcoded on the script. What fails is something related to the "$1".

P.D: I know there are other ways to append a file. I've been using them for now, but still I would like to fix this code or at least to know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 7):

Variable expansion happens later than tilde expansion:

> The  order  of  expansions is: brace expansion, **tilde** expansion, parameter, **variable**
>          and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion),
>          word splitting, and pathname expansion.

(from `man bash`, emphasis mine)

Therefore, bash can't expand the tilde in the variable value. If you really assign the value directly in an assignment, don't use the quotes: tilde expansion happens on the assigned value.

```
test=~/.test
```

If the filename needs quoting, keep the beginning up to the first slash out of the quotes:

```
test=~username/'path that/needs quoting'
```

Comment: Or at least, leave the `~` out of the quotes: `test=~"/.test"` (for the times when there is whitespace that needs to be quoted).

Comment: @chepner: That doesn't work. `test=~/'.test'` does, though.

Comment: Huh, never noticed that.

Comment: @chepner: I haven't either, but tested now. Explained by the first paragraph of Tilde Expansion in `man bash`.

Answer (score -1):

Below expression won't work

```
test=~"/.test"
```

Best way to give absolute path to .test file. e.g.

```
test="/home/user/.test"
```